# AVAudioPlayer is not playing any sound

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation

I have made a class which handles audio that is played in my app:

```
import AVFoundation    

class GSAudio{
    var soundFileNameURL: NSURL = NSURL()
    var soundFileName = ""
    var soundPlay = AVAudioPlayer()

    func playSound (soundFile: String){

        soundFileName = soundFile
        soundFileNameURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(soundFileName, ofType: "aif", inDirectory:"Sounds")!)
        do{
            try soundPlay = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundFileNameURL)
        } catch {
            print("Could not play sound file!")
        }

        soundPlay.prepareToPlay()
        soundPlay.play()
    }
}
```

But the problem is when I call this code by using something like `GSAudio().playSound("Start")` from a different class, the sound does not play. Does anyone know why this is? Any help is appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: Is "GSAudio().playSound("Start")" the exact code you use? If so, you need to declare playSound as:

class fun playSound(soundFile: String)

Comment: Something doesn't add up here, because soundPlay is an instance variable, you need an instance of GSAudio created to use it. And that instance has to persist until the sound finishes. I'm guessing you create the instance and then it gets destroyed before the sound plays - it's happened to me enough times! Keep a persistant reference to the instance until it's finished.

Answer (score 0):

I have method AVAudioPlayer and its working fine when the button click action then perform this below method play well, but You want to call class and method (ex 'GSAudio().playSound("Start")') from different class, you create the delegate method to call, its work well.

```
@IBAction func btnPlayAction(sender: AnyObject) {

                let fileURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: previewUrl)!
                let soundData = NSData(contentsOfURL: fileURL)

                do {
                    playerVal = try AVAudioPlayer(data: soundData!)
                }
                catch {
                    print("Something bad happened. Try catching specific errors to narrow things down",error)
                }

                playerVal.delegate = self
                playerVal.prepareToPlay()

                playerVal.play()
}
```

hope its helpful

Answer (score 0):

Check Your Sound File (URL) Path..(print That) and Checkout  **file://** Is There Or Not That's Main Problem In Your Sound ULR Ok Add it **File://**

//Or Use this One

**NSURL *SoundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:YourFilePath];**

**Try This One And Let me Know is i'm Correct or not**

Answer (score 0):

I have a helper on GitHub that does what you want. It's properly better to make this class a Singleton so you can control your music better and don't create multiple instances of your helper.

https://github.com/crashoverride777/Swift-Music-Helper